# Fancybox2 show popup centered inside a div

Tags: jquery, popup, fancybox, parent, fancybox-2

I need to center a fancybox2 popup (`div` with text) inside a another `div` (with *class* `.popup-container`) and not in the center of the screen.

I tried with this, but nothing:

```
$(".js-add-form").fancybox({       
    maxWidth: 850,
    maxHeight: 570,
    fitToView: false,
    width: '850',
    height: '570',
    autoSize: false,
    closeClick: false,
    openEffect: 'none',
    closeEffect: 'none',
    parent: '.popup-container',
    helpers: {
        overlay: {
            locked: false
        }
    }
});
```

Someone know ho to resolve?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make sure you *parent* container `.popup-container` has `position: relative;` in your CSS like :

```
.popup-container {  
    position: relative;
    /* other css rules */
}
```

**EDIT** :
You may also need to force the fancybox wrap container to center via CSS like

```
.fancybox-wrap {
    position: relative !important;
    left: auto !important;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Bear in mind that the *parent* container (`.popup-container`) needs to be at least `50px` wider than your fancybox `maxWidth` setting. Also make sure you add

```
autoCenter: false
```

... to your fancybox API options so the fancybox wrapper doesn't re-center relatively to the screen while scrolling down the page.

See updated **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/c2k6yvs7/5/)**

Comment: Mh no, my situation is a little different: http://jsfiddle.net/c2k6yvs7/4/
I need to put the popup inside the black box :(